# Nontrivial IEC 61131-3 Code Examples

Tags: embedded, plc, industrial, iec61131-3

I am currently developing a method for symbolically executing and testing IEC 61131-3 applications.
For evaluating my approach, I require non-trivial programs written in any of the languages defined in the standard.

Are there any openly accessible code bases I could use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OSCAT libraries](http://www.oscat.de/) is the biggest open code base written in IEC61131-3 afaik. They provide different libraries for different use cases and for different plc vendors

Furthermore there are some example programs available on [Beckhoff Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index_en.htm). For almost every library they provide a sample section. One of the biggest samples is the OOP extension sample (OOP extensions are included in the new version of IEC61131-3, not sure if you are interested in it).

Another source of examples is the [Codesys Store](https://store.codesys.com/). They have some free and some paid examples.

And one more I like (but its only in german). [M. Seitz](http://www.es.hs-mannheim.de/sps40/SimAT/SimAT.html) the author of a good plc programming book provides some accompanying samples, one of them a bit bigger (coffee machine). There is also a simulation and control library available.

Answer (score 1):

A very good source for examples is Beckhoff's information system which is also available for download.

You can find good examples of different methods for example under different libraries.

Some links:

- [Programming Reference](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/99079191938313867.html&id=579375192146720936) (Good source)
- [OOP Sample](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_sampleprogram1/36028797119942923.html&id=5471687397075990290)
- [Standard library](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_standard/index.html&id=7772077850773153575) (Library containing IEC standard functions)